# How to autoload Zend Framework module models?

Tags: zend-framework

I am building a new CMS in Zend Framework and I don't have much exposure to ZF. Client requires two sections called Admin and FE. So, I have structured my application structure as follows.

```
- SITE
-- application
---- configs
---- layouts
---- modules
-------- default
------------ controllers
------------ forms
------------ models
------------ views
------------ Bootstrap.php
-------- admin
------------ controllers
------------ forms
------------ models
------------ views
------------ Bootstrap.php
---- Bootstrap.php
-- public
-- library
-- index.php
```

My structure is working fine and layouts and controllers are loading when I am accessing site like http://site or http://site/admin.

My question is
1.) How will I autoload my models in modules. In the model specific bootstrap file I have added below code. But it is not working.

```
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap 
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/modules/admin/',
            'namespace' => '',
            'resourceTypes' => array(
                'form' => array(
                    'path' => 'forms/',
                    'namespace' => 'Form_',
                ),
                'model' => array(
                    'path' => 'models/',
                    'namespace' => 'CPModel_'
                )
            ),
        ));
        return $autoloader;
    }
}
```

2.) How will I use different layouts for different module?

Answer (score 3):

Two questions here:

1. Autoloading models
2. Module-specific layout

For autoloading models, first make sure that your module bootstrap class extends `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`. This will register a resource autoloader that includes a mapping so that a model class named `Admin_Model_User` can be stored in the file `application/modules/admin/models/User.php` (note the plural model**s** in the path name). For the usage you describe above, it does not appear that you need to define any such mappings yourself.

There is a bit of trickiness associated to the default module. IIRC, the default module uses the appnamespace, typically defaulting to `Application_`. So, for example, a user model in the default module would be named `Application_Model_User` and stored in the file `application/modules/default/models/User.php`. [If that doesn't work, then try naming `Default_Model_User`]

[However, if you really insist on an empty appnamespace for your admin module and a prefix of CPModel for your models - as your example suggests - then some of this changes.]

The upshot is that since most of these folders are not on the include_path, the system needs to be told at some point what class prefixes to associate/map with what directories.

For module-specific layouts, typically I create a [front-controller plugin](http://devzone.zend.com/1224/front-controller-plugins-in-zend-framework/) that implements the `preDispatch()` hook. If you keep your layouts at the top-level in `application/layouts/scripts/`, then your plugin can look something like the following stored in `application/plugins/Layout.php`:

```
class Application_Plugin_Layout extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout($request->getModuleName());
    }
}
```

Register your plugin in your app-level `Bootstrap`, either via `applications/config/application.ini`:

```
resources.frontController.plugin.layout = "Application_Plugin_Layout"
```

or in the app-level `Bootstrap` in `application/Bootstrap.php`:

```
protected function _initPlugins()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugin_Layout());
}
```

Then, for example, your admin layout could be stored in `application/layouts/scripts/admin.phtml`.

Comment: Weinaub - you are creating "plugins.Layout.php" file in application directory or you are creatign "Layout.php" file in "application/plugins" directory??

Comment: @Saurabh: Thanks for catching the typo. ;-) Fixed. Class named `Application_Plugin_Layout` in file `application/plugins/Layout.php` (note plural plugin**s** in path).

Comment: I also think that registering plugins from application.ini is not allowed in zf 1.11 and we have to rename the layout file from "layout.phtml" to "default.phtml" to work.. please confirm..

Comment: @Saurabh you can name your layout anything you want. You can set the default layout using the line: `resources.layout.layout = master` in your application.ini. Yes you can register plugins in application.ini in ZF 1.11, it's [core to the application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html).

Comment: @Saurabh: You _can_ register plugins in `application.ini` v1.11. The only constraint is that the plugin must not require any constructor parameters.