# can any one suggest a step by step guide to add admin module in default zend framework project?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

I have decided to use ZF for one of my PHP project. But I am heavily confused with how to add a admin module with my site? I read some articles like this one (http://www.amazium.com/blog/create-modular-application-with-zend) and many other. They are propose a different way of doing this. **I want to know is there any standard approach from Zend** ( I am sure they khow almost every site needs a admin module)??

Or can someone please suggest **a step by step guide on how to add a admin module in default zend framework project.**

BTW: I am using zend studio 9.0 as IDE (if that matters)..

Comment: If you are voting for close then please mention the reason in comments!!

Comment: for those voting for close - can you please explain me why this question is "not constructive" .. you can edit the question if you think its not "not constructive"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume ZF 1.11:

in your application.ini make sure these lines are here (may be a little over kill but it works):

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = ""
resources.modules = ""
```

your path should look like:

```
/application
    /configs
    /controllers
    /forms
    /layouts
    /models
    /modules
        /admin
            /controllers
            /models
            /forms
            /views
                /filters
                /helpers
                /scripts
       Bootstrap.php //in your admin folder bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
    /views
Bootstrap.php //application level bootstrap
/docs
/library
/public
```

the path requirements except for the bootstrap can be accomplished by running the ZF Tool command `zf create module admin`

The really important thing to remember is that each module needs a Bootstrap.php file at it's root. This facilitates (among other things) the autoloader.

```
<?php
class Admin_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {
    //put your code here
}
```

this is all you need for a module bootstrap.

[EDIT]
to select a different layout (create a second layout) for a controller (admin for example) the simple way is in each controller:

```
public function preDispatch() {

        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('admin');
    }
```

if you need to change lots of layouts in lots of controllers you'll likely need a controller plugin (not my area of experience).

Comment: Super thanks for the answer!! but how would I separate the admin layout from my site layout? I also wants to separate the public resources for site and admin... how?

Comment: @Saurabh: For per-module layout, see the second part of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256280/how-to-autoload-zend-framework-module-models/10257309#10257309